# Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator? DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

Getting this error `Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator` , when I use `{ useIsFocused } ";`. I really tried hard but did not find any proper solution , couldsomeone please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

import TabMenu from "../navigations/TabNavigation";
import SideBarMenu from "../components/SideBarMenu/SideBarMenu";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  console.log("@@ props", navigation);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(" I am workign");
  }, [isFocused]);
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <SideBarMenu {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabMenu} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use this in the navigator. You could use `useIsFocused` in a component rendered as a screen inside the navigator. For example, you could use it inside `TabMenu` component

Comment: Actually, I want to hit endpoint when user click on menu . It actually drawer menu when user click on it I am firing  useIsFocused() but it throw `navigation object` couldn't find

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. If you want to trigger an event when the side menu screen is opened you could use `useIsFocused` in the `drawerContent` component (this can be a component that uses hooks like any other).

The problem is that you can only use `useIsFocused` inside a screen, and you are trying to use it in a navigator.